# Обработчик php не учитывает условия

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

В Общем проблема такая, при обработке post в php скрипт полностью выполняется и не учитывает условия.
Ниже код самого php скрипта и ajax.
Если я к примеру отправляю такое **onclick="trn('21aaa это отредактировано через консоль браузера');"** в post и смотрю на ответ, сначала идет успешное выполнение а потом только ошибка.

```js
//Ответ скрипта в консоле браузера
//{status: "success", message: "Successfully"}
//{status: "warning", message: "Unknow data."}

    trn = function(id) {
      $('.table-responsive').append('<div class="box-loader"></div>');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script.php',
        data: {
          id: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('div.box-loader').remove();
          var m = JSON.parse(data);
          if (m['status'] === 'success') {
            $('tbody #trn-' + id).hide('slow').remove;
          }
          console.log(m);
          msg(m['status'], m['message']);
        },
        error: function(data) {
          $('div.box-loader').remove();
          msg('error', 'Unknown ajax error.');
        }
      });
    }
```

```
    if(1) {//Check xmlhttprequest
            $test = '1';//Post (gettype( $test ); result string )
            if(isset($test) && is_numeric($test) && is_int(intval($test))) {
                $id = $test;//Recheck
                $trn = 0;//Select Sql
                if($trn != 1) {
                    $user = 1;//Select Sql
                    if($user > 0) {
                        echo "Updated";//Update Sql
                    }
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message' => "Successfully."));
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => "Already or does not exist.."));
                }
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'warning','message' => "Unknow data."));
            }
            
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => "Access denied."));
        }
```

Comment: если вы два раза видите ответ, то и запрос отправляете тоже два раза

Comment: Странно, а как такое может быть вообще? Событие ведь onclick, на кнопку нажимаю один раз 100%

Comment: Полагаю вы отправляете строку,а условия распространяются на число. Какие конкретно сыпятся ошибки? //{status: "warning", message: "Unknow data."} - значит я прав, шлите число, а не строку

Comment: откройте вкладку Сеть в консоли браузера, то посмотрите каике запросы отправляются. поставьте брейкпоинт в функцию отправки.

Comment: По сути проблема такая, к примеру я хитрожопый юзер который вместе с int решил что-то еще отправить, и с помощью консоли браузера отредактировал данные в элементе onclick="trn('21')" И отправил, обработчик по идее должен все это пресечь. Но тут происходит странность, обработчик делает вид что все норм и только потом сообщает юзеру что он отправил левые данные, хотя при этом уже произвел sql запрос..

Comment: Почему у вас в ответе консоли 2 ответа, если вы на кнопку нажали 1 раз, ничего не смущает?

Comment: если вы знаете что там только числа то и берите intval($_POST['id']), а не в условии его смотрите..

Comment: Ну как я понял, data: {  id: id  } по идее это int, но через gettype получается string. Хоть данные в таком виде trn(21) или trn('21') таком.

Comment: И кст проверил, действительно почему-то идет 2 post. Один корректный а второй поддельный. Кто подскажет почему такое происходит?

Comment: Именно из-за того что первый валидный, он и производит запись в базу. Недостаточно кода чтобы понять в чем дело, так как у вас урезанная версия, нужен HTML + JavaScript

Comment: Это я уже понял, что он первый post обрабатывает. Из за того что он действительно корректный. Но почему корректный код был отправлен, ведь на месте того кода уже был некорректный код...<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="trn('21');">..</a> Это фактически и есть весь код :)

Comment: Код по сути простой как пробка. 1) Кнопка "onclick" 2) ajax POST 3)PHP обработчик.